# On click of all radio button show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have written the code: 
On click of all the radiobutton then only show the div even if single radio is unchecked hide the div.

works on single id but if all added doesn't work.

`html`

```
<li class="list-group">
    <input type="radio" id="one">
    <input type="radio" id="two">
    <input type="radio" id="three">
    <input type="radio" id="four">
</li>
<div class="chk-message16"></div>
```

`JS`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".chk-message16").hide();
    var Onee = $("#one, #two, #three, #four");

    Onee.change(function () {
        $(".list-group > .chk-message").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: hi now cehck to my answer i think you wan to this

Comment: first of all there should have some reset kind of facility or you should use checkbox to select/deselect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi now try to this way

you write the wrong code in jquery check to this and correct our code .

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".chk-message16").hide();
                var Onee = $("#one, #two, #three, #four");
                       
   
             

                Onee.on('change', function() {       
                    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 4){
                      $(".chk-message16").show();
                    }else{
                      $(".chk-message16").hide();
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <li class="list-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="one">
    <input type="checkbox" id="two">
    <input type="checkbox" id="three">
    <input type="checkbox" id="four">
    </li>
    <div class="chk-message16">hide show div</div>
```

Comment: this one is perfect but the radio button dose'nt get uncheck and hide the div

Comment: than you used to check box

Comment: If `li.list-group` has `ul` parent element , selector `".list-group + .chk-message16"` return different results

Comment: Than you can used to this ".chk-message16" only not this ".list-group + .chk-message16"

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/taeu839b/)

```
$(".chk-message16").hide();
var Onee = $("#one, #two, #three, #four");

Onee.change(function () {
    $(".chk-message16").show();
});
```

Change selector from `$(".list-group > .chk-message").show();` to `$(".chk-message16").show();`

added name to checkbox.

[FIDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/taeu839b/2/)

```
$(".chk-message16").hide();
var Onee = $("#one, #two, #three, #four");
//var class = $('input:radio:checked').length
Onee.change(function () {
    if($(':radio:checked').length == 4)
    $(".chk-message16").show();

});
```

Comment: OK but, even on one radio button checked it shows the div, I want on all the radio button then only it should show div.

Comment: wait i will change my answer

Answer (score 0):

whenever u want to select multiple options never use radio button for it.
radio button is used to select single out of multiple.
For purpose of multiple selection always use checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

also make a note to select single out of multiple radio button at a time give them same name :

```
ex.
 Female:<input type="radio" name="gen" checked="checked">
 Male :<input type="radio" name="gen">
```